# ie8 the div going vertically down

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

in ie8 the entire div goes completely down
but i wanted this div to be horizontally aligned...
can you tell me how to fix the issue

even in fiddle it goes down
http://jsfiddle.net/VXXPC/2/embedded/result/

it works perfectly in chrome
http://www.defie.co/testing/twitter-bootstrap-558bc52/docs/examples/marketing-alternate.html

```
<div class="span3" style="width: 516px;">
                <h4 class="taxInformation">Tax Information</h4>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Seller Permit No</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                      <input type="text" id="inputEmail">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Tax Rate</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                      <input type="text" id="inputEmail">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Tax District</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                      <input type="text" id="inputEmail">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Federal ID No</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                      <input type="text" id="inputEmail">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h4 class="accountingContactInfo">Accounting Contact Info</h4>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Name</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                      <input type="text" id="inputEmail">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                      <input type="text" id="inputEmail">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Phone</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                      <input type="text" id="inputEmail">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Credit Limit</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                      <input type="text" id="inputEmail">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h4 class="bankInfo">Bank Info</h4>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Bank Name</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                      <input type="text" id="inputEmail">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Telephone</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                      <input type="text" id="inputEmail">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Account No</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                      <input type="text" id="inputEmail">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Bank Contact</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                      <input type="text" id="inputEmail">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Terms</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                      <input type="text" id="inputEmail">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h4 class="bankInfo">Notes</h4>
                <div class="control-group">
                      <textarea style="width: 380px;" rows="3" cols="50"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div style="margin-left: 95px;">
                  <input style="width: 108px;" name="Finish" value="Save File" class="checkout-button saveFileButton" type="submit">
                  <input name="Finish" value="Delete" class="checkout-button deleteButton" type="submit" style="width: 107px;padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;">
                </div>

              </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try decrease the width of `div.span3`.

For example

```
<div class="span3" style="width: 456px;">
```

Avoid using inline style in your HTML, set these attributes like `width` of `height` in CSS.
By the way, if the window width is resized to less than 1000px, this DIV will still go vertically down.

Answer (score 0):

You have a float element and an inline-block element after. Try to float both of them.

```
.redButton {
clear: none;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply...its not working i wanted sth similar to this https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3IBJKENGE7RZzF6V3Y0MEVqcDA/edit

Comment: Changed my answer. Try this one.